# Cordova plugin for opening SMS app on android

Tags: cordova

Is there a way to open the default SMS app in Android, from a Cordova app? I am aware of the OpenApplication plugin which opens any external application. But, default SMS app could be different across Android phones (e.g. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.messaging, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.concentriclivers.mms.com.android.mms, etc). I am looking for generic way of opening the default SMS app.

Answer (score 0):

I think this plugin is what you need : [Cordova SMS Plugin](https://github.com/cordova-sms/cordova-sms-plugin)

Comment: I guess, that is to 'send SMS'. While, what I need is a way to open the SMS app - to read messages. Something akin to `$window.OpenApplication('com.google.android.gm')`, which is for opening the gmail app - a mail app found on most (if not all) android devices.